# Rails generate: xml.display can't generate <display></display>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-3, render

```
xml.instruct! :xml, :version=>"1.0" 
xml.urlset do
    xml.url do
        xml.title @tuan.title
        xml.url "http://www.geilibuy.com"+mytuan_url(@tuan)
        xml.data do
            xml.display do
                xml.website "dd"
            end
        end
    end
end
```

The above code can't be rendered as:

```
<data>
<display>dd</display>
</data>
```

The display node doesn't exist. It seems display may be a keyword of rails. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
xml.tag!(:display) do
  # foobar
end
```

for things that are keywords etc.

Answer (score 0):

it's reallly display is a keywords of ruby,

so now i use xxx.xml.erb instead of xx.xml.builder